# I want to emove quote on echo json_encode();

Tags: php, arrays, json

Result is:

`{"plate":"LQT 883","model":"-1584460854"}`

Actually I want this value as following:

`{"plate":"LQT 883","model":-1584460854}`

Here more Code, sorry

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "plate" => $randomString .= $result_4 .= $plate, 
    "model" => $row['item']
), true);
```

Comment: How do you set the value before you encode it? If you set it as an integer, it won't have quotes. If you set it as a string, it will have quotes.

Comment: this here $row['item']

Comment: That doesn't tell me how you _set_ the value. Is `$row['item']` an array containing the above data? If so, then do `$row['item']['model'] = (int)$row['item'['model']];` before you encode it.

Comment: Can you share enough code for others to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have done it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `json_encode()` to encode the value as an integer, you need to cast it as one:

```
"model" => (int)$row['item']
```